# JQueryUI Autocomplete populate number of textboxes

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Let say i have 3 textboxes :

1. product
2. buyPrice
3. sellPrice

the product textbox is autocomplete and it works well already, but i want to populate default buyPrice and default sellPrice which i can get from my table and i can include that in json i return. Is it possible?? i googled it but still can't find good example on it.

this is piece of my code :

```
$( "#product" ).autocomplete({
    source: '/product/product'
});
```

sample of my Product list json :

```
["x10","f10","f25"]
```

And 1 more question. Is it possible that i preload My Product List so it no need to go to server everytime user type something in product textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event of the autocomplete.

The response you are getting is not going to work well with the autocompleter. According to the docs the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) needs to return a json object with additional fields there, not a simple array. Like this:

```
{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    buy:   100,
    sell:  200
  },
```

Then in the select callback, you can use those fields like

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    $("#buyPrice").val( ui.item.buy );
    $("#sellPrice").val( ui.item.sell );

    return false;
  }
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HN38B/)

Comment: it works fine.. thanks so much.. and 1 more thing.. can i preload all list to the json so it no need to send to server everytime user type? i can use iterate in scripting for that but feel like its not a proper way?

Comment: Sure you can, just make an call to fetch the result list and after that initialize the autocompleter, using the data as source.